# Cypress Test Runner stuck at start up and have infinite loading

Tags: cypress

Even before any test execution, I've run into a problem. My Cypress Test Runner is stuck on the very beginning, and has infinite loading.

Have tried reinstalling, but still the same.

I am using MacOS Big Sur, and this is what comes up when I type `cypress --version`

```
Cypress package version: 9.2.0
Cypress binary version: 9.2.0
Electron version: 15.2.0
Bundled Node version: 16.5.0
```

[image]

---

I've also tried `DEBUG=cypress:* ./node_modules/.bin/cypress open`, and I get the following:

```
current & mean memory and CPU usage by process group:
```

and then table with contents, which repeats every ~10sec.

Has anyone else encountered this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found an issue, the node version was 17, and for some reason I got the error `--openssl-legacy-provider is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS`

After I changed the node version to 16.x it works.

Comment: also works in node version 14

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was because of the `http` instead `https` protocol for the host I wanted to test by `cy.visit`. 
There is the [issue](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/25891)  in cypress github regarding this problem. Despite it has been closed people (including me) are still facing this stuff so just keep your eyes on this issue